# Container files not updated when changed from the host mapped volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./.docker/node.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - D:\Proj\Web:/app
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on: 
      - 'db'
    networks:
      - holder-network
    restart: on-failure
    tty: true


  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - holder-network
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: holder_db
      MYSQL_USER: holder_usr
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rd


networks:
  holder-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data:
```

And the `node.dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:7.10

MAINTAINER Juliano Nunes

RUN mkdir /var/www

RUN npm install nodemon -g

WORKDIR /var/www

ADD . /var/www

RUN npm install

CMD nodemon
```

I'm changing the files under `D:\Proj\Web` from the host, however it doesn't update the files in the container. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the error. My `docker-compose.yml` was using `/app` as the path and `node.dockerfile` was using `/var/www`.

Here's the updated (working) version:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./.docker/node.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - D:\Proj\Web:/var/www
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on: 
      - 'db'
    networks:
      - holder-network
    restart: on-failure
    tty: true


  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - holder-network
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rd
      MYSQL_DATABASE: holder_db
      MYSQL_USER: holder_usr
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: P@ssw0rd


networks:
  holder-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data:
```

Comment: Same problem, same solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To map a host volume in a container running on docker for windows, you need to ensure your drive is shared into the embedded VM. Otherwise, the directory will mount from the VM's filesystem which will be empty at that location. You need to go into the docker settings on Windows and add the D drive to the shared directory list. See docker's documentation on this here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives

Comment: The drive is already shared on Docker Settings. The directory is not empty in the container, the files are copied when the container is started, however if I edit the files from Windows (host), the changes are not reflected in the guest.

Comment: Docker doesn't copy files when the container starts, it's a mapping of a directory directly into the container. What commands are you using to verify that the files are initially updated but remaining at a prior state later?

Comment: I've found that in my `docker-compose.yml` I was referencing a different path  than `node.dockerfile`. That was my mistake.